# how to make something repeat x amount of times every n seconds in python?

Tags: python

Let's say, i want a beeping sound be heard a total of 5 times, with 5 second break with each beep. For that, i tried using threading module, and made this:

```
import threading
import winsound
i = 0
def beep():
   global i
   while i < 5:
         i += 1
         threading.Timer(5.0, beep).start()
         winsound.PlaySound("beep", winsound.SND_FILENAME)

beep()
```

This code repeats it succesfully i amount of times, but ignores a time interval and instead does it on a much faster, equally distributed unchangeable interval. I know that happens because of how while loop works, but I cant seem to find any alternative. Every piece of information would come in handy!

Comment: Did you mean to place the `threading.Timer(5.0, beep).start()` outside the `while` loop? Perhaps after the `while`?

Comment: do you really want to run the timer in a different thread? shouldn't you be running the timer in the current thread?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got this to work ok:

```py
import threading
import winsound

def beep(n):
    if n == 0:
        return
    for i in range(5):
        winsound.Beep(4000,100)
    threading.Timer(5.0, beep, args=(n-1,)).start()

beep(4)
```

Comment: This definetly works like a charm, and although I realized my program needs something else, it one hundred percent answers the specified question. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

use time module

import time

time.sleep(int x in seconds)

Comment: I do not have a problem with a method repeating every n seconds. What I am struggling with is limiting how many times the method will repeat every n seconds before stopping.